# Can I create a jsrender template for this json object?

Tags: jsrender

Can I create a jsrender template to access values 'first' and 'age' in this json object?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var names = { 
    "smith": [ 
        {
            "first" : "bill",
            "age" : "21"
        }
    ],
    "jones": [
        {
            "first" : "mary",
            "age" : "25"
        }
    ]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The schema seems strange. But you can write this:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{:smith[0].first}}: Age: {{:smith[0].age}}
    {{:jones[0].first}}: Age: {{:jones[0].age}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Boris.  I notice you responding frequently and promptly to questions.  It must interfere witj your development time!  I am new to jsrender/jsviews.  I thought this structure may have allowed me to access specific rows.  I have since posted on here : http://www.borismoore.com/2012/03/approaching-beta-whats-changing-in_06.html and if I can get what I'm after from that post I will scrap this schema.  Thanks again. Neil.